# How to calculate returns from a vector of prices?

Tags: r

I have to calculate the return of a vector that gives a historical price series of a stock.  The vector is of a form:

```
a <- c(10.25, 11.26, 14, 13.56)
```

I need to calculate daily gain/loss (%) - i.e. what is the gain it has from 10.25 to 11.26 then from 11.26 to 14 etc.

Is there a function to calculate this automatically?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using your sample data, I think you mean the following:

```
a <- c(10.25, 11.26, 14, 13.56) 
> diff(a)/a[-length(a)]
[1]  0.09853659  0.24333925 -0.03142857
```

`diff` returns the vector of lagged differences and `a[-length(a)]` drops the last element of a.

Comment: Hmm I should get: 9.853659 % (from 10.25 to 11.26) 24.33393 % (from 11.26 to 14) -3.142857 % (from 14 to 13.56)

Comment: Yes, this is the same as my result.

Comment: Feel free to multiply this by any number you wish.

Comment: THank you Andrie, Yes, I need 100 to understand the real % gain/loss...ok!

Comment: Save a few characters (at the possible cost of comprehensibility) with `diff(a)/tail(a,-1)`

Comment: @BenBolker, `diff(a)/tail(a,-1)` does not give the return, which is defined as: `R = [p(t) - p(t-1)] / p(t-1)`

Comment: The length of the resulting vector is not the same as the input vector.  How do i get a vector of the same length?

Comment: @FistOfFury - you just can't.  By definition, when you compute returns, you "lose one observation", there is just no way around it. So the resulting vectors will be the same length as the input vector -1. You can see this by inspecting the formula: to compute ONE return (say at time `t`), you need TWO observations (`t` and `t-1`)

Answer (score 25):

You may find the functions in `quantmod` relevant for your work:

```
> require(quantmod)
> Delt(a)
     Delt.1.arithmetic
[1,]                NA
[2,]        0.09853659
[3,]        0.24333925
[4,]       -0.03142857
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the exact relationship that returns are equal to the exponent of log returns minus one.  Thus, if `Prices` contains your prices, the following will give you your returns:

```
Returns = exp(diff(log(Prices))) - 1
```

Note that this is an *exact* relationship, rather than the approximate relationship given in the answer by @PBS.

Answer (score 1):

A more detailed example with multiple time series:

```
############ Vector  ############

vPrice <- (10.25, 11.26, 14, 13.56) 
n = length(vPrice)

#Log returns

log_ret <- diff(log(vPrice)) # or = log(vPrice[-1]/vPrice[-n]) because "..[-i]" removes the i'th item of the vector
log_ret

#Simple returns

simple_ret <- diff(vPrice)/vPrice[1:(n-1)] # or = diff(vPrice)/vPrice[-n]
simple_ret


############ Multiple Time series ############

head(EuStockMarkets)

mPrice <-  EuStockMarkets
n = dim(mPrice)[1] #Nb rows

log_ret <- diff(log(mPrice))
head(log_ret)

simple_ret <- diff(mPrice)/mPrice[1:(n-1),]
head(simple_ret)


#Total Returns

total_log_ret <- colSums(log_ret,2) #just a sum for log-returns
total_log_ret
total_Simple_ret <- apply(1+simple_ret, 2, prod)-1 # product of simple returns
total_Simple_ret

##################

#From simple to log returns 
all.equal(log(1+total_Simple_ret),total_log_ret) #should be true

#From Log to simple returns 
all.equal( total_Simple_ret,exp(total_log_ret)-1) #should be true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ret<-diff(log(a))
```

This will give you the geometric returns - return follow a lognormal distribution (lower boundary is -100% since prices are always non-negative), so the `ln(prices)` follows a normal distribution (therefore you might see returns smaller than -1 or -100%).

For the "normal" range of returns, the difference between the `[P(t+1)-P(t)]/P(t)` and the `LN(P(t+1)/P(t))` should be negligible. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but why use an approximate relationship when it is not hard to calculate an exact one, as in the answer I provide?

Comment: Also, if you're using monthly, yearly, etc. returns (that will be larger than, e.g. daily returns) the errors in this method will get you into trouble fast.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is the `ROC` function of the `TTR` package:

```
library(TTR)
a <- c(10.25, 11.26, 14, 13.56)
ROC(a, type = "discrete")
## [1]          NA  0.09853659  0.24333925 -0.03142857
```

`type = continuous` (which is also the default) gives log-returns:

```
ROC(a)
## [1]          NA  0.09397892  0.21780071 -0.03193305
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```r
(PRICE / lag(PRICE)-1) * 100
```